# The New Age Philosophy of Evolution stating that working towards Thoughtlessness and Nothingness is fundamentally Flawed

Tags: theravada, meditation, karma, vipassana, ethics

Though this video is in Hinglish - some casual dialogues are in Hindi but most of the conversation happens in English https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Uf-eoAij5o , [Anand Gandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anand_Gandhi) - Director and Scriptwriter for the philosophical movie "[Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus_(film))" gives a perfect explanation of what we have to do as humans, Purpose of Life, and in fact, argues that attaining the nothingness or the thoughtlessness is fundamentally wrong using evolution theory. Is there an opposition argument to what he has stated?

Answer (score 2):

"The freedom of my swinging arms ends at your nose."

This video promotes the value of developing consciousness beyond personal concerns into a consciousness that embraces the world around us.  In the suttas, one reads the equivalent:

> [AN9.33:6.2](https://suttacentral.net/an9.33/en/sujato#an9.33:6.2): If someone should say, ‘I do not know or see where the perception of the dimension of infinite space ceases’,  they should be told:  ‘It’s when a mendicant, going totally beyond the dimension of infinite space, aware that “consciousness is infinite”, enters and remains in the dimension of infinite consciousness.  That’s where the perception of the dimension of infinite space ceases.’

Infinite space is unsatisfactory when one's swinging arm hits another's nose. Infinite consciousness is aware of noses and arms and also aware of the time for swinging arms or stepping forward with noses.

Notably, the suttas continue beyond the dimension of infinite consciousness. With increasing consciousness we discover that costs and benefits are mixed. Hunting skills lead to obsession with video games that produce no actual food. Huntington's disease leads to [lower risk of cancer](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/02/180212084458.htm#:%7E:text=Summary%3A,cancer%20than%20the%20general%20population.). Consciousness mitigates some suffering but doesn't end it. The suttas go on to describe what lies beyond infinite consciousness.

> [AN9.33:7.2](https://suttacentral.net/an9.33/en/sujato#an9.33:7.2): If someone should say, ‘I do not know or see where the perception of the dimension of infinite consciousness ceases’, they should be told: ‘It’s when a mendicant, going totally beyond the dimension of infinite consciousness, aware that “there is nothing at all”, enters and remains in the dimension of nothingness. That’s where the perception of the dimension of infinite consciousness ceases.’

The dimension of nothingness should not be experienced as life-ending nihilistic apathy.

> [SN54.9:3.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn54.9/en/sujato#sn54.9:3.3): Becoming horrified, repelled, and disgusted with this body, they looked for someone to slit their wrists.

Instead, the Buddha taught:

> [SN54.9:7.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn54.9/en/sujato#sn54.9:7.2): In the same way, when this immersion due to mindfulness of breathing is developed and cultivated it’s peaceful and sublime, a deliciously pleasant meditation. And it disperses and settles unskillful qualities on the spot whenever they arise.

So the Buddha might agree with the video in that fiercely grasping at nothingness is silly (i.e., "bulls**t" in the video). But the Buddha also noted that infinite consciousness itself is ultimately impermanent and unsatisfactory, and certainly not an end to suffering.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  Buddhism isn't beholden to evolutionary theory!  What makes evolution the standard bearer for what constitutes right livelihood?

Answer (score 0):

Theory of Evolution is not a theory at all. Just listen to what it essentially says, it says that things are the way they are because other ways died out(Natural Selection). That is not any logic at all.Although things change based on past karma, we can't say that the modern theory of evolution is correct.
The discussion on youtube link is very basic and doesn't even start to acknowledge Dhamma.
Dhamma doesn't say the purpose of human existence is thoughtlessness or feelinglessness.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the video yet, but I'd say that no scientic theory would be able to tell us how are we supposed to live or what is valuable to follow and what to abandon. Science shows what is the world and what is the relation between its parts; philosophy, ethics, spirituality and religion try to give us a "why" should we follow one way of life or other.

Another question is whether is or not possible to attain complete liberation from *dukkha*. Probably most buddhist would say that it possible. But I'm not sure if the Theory of Evolution would be able to demonstrate the reality of that possibility. If there's a branch of scientific research that could give us some answers, I'd say that it's Neuroscience and science of cognition in general.